# Removing string starting from one special character to another special character ending

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to remove the string which is there in the BOLD. from the same column i want to remove all the Junk data.

**tse-ed-t_**Staticdata:**tse-ed-t_**StaticMember,**tse-ed-t_**Result:tse-ed-t_ResultMember

**jppfs_cor_**StateConsolidated:**jppfs_cor_**StateConsolidatedMember
**jpcrp_cor_**ConsolidatedSegments:**adzdp040300-s2r_f05274-000_**Memberofdetails

Answer (score 0):

This will help for a variable:

```
declare @string  as varchar(4000) = 'tse-ed-t_Staticdata:tse-ed-t_StaticMember,tse-ed-t_Result:tse-ed-t_ResultMember'

set @string = replace(@string, 'tse-ed-t_', '')

select @string
```

For a table update to column with the value

```
replace([ColumnToChange], 'tse-ed-t_', '')
```